# Item permissions changed

Tags: active-directory, security

I have a question because i cant explain why something happend. Suddenly the item permissions on several items are changed. An AD group is gone as a permissions group and instead i see the SHAREPOINT\system account with full control on the items.

Does this sound familiar? I cant recall any weird things happening (workflow maybe?).

thank you in advance.